# Tooltip behaves old style

Tags: jquery, html, tooltip

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Trivandrum Diaries</title>
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/get-shit-done.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/gsdk-checkbox.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/gsdk-morphing.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/gsdk-radio.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.flexisel.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.tagsinput.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/controls.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/chartist.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-select.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/11c5094818.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/demo.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/examples.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/gsdk.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/pe-icon-7-stroke.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-ct-azure navbar-transparent navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button id="menu-toggle" type="button" class="navbar-toggle">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar bar1"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar bar2"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar bar3"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Trivandrum Diaries</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" data-nav-image='assets/img/blog_1.png'>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="btn-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top" data-trigger="manual"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-newspaper-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-tags" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Discover</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Stats</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is my code, but my tooltip shows like the image below [Tool Top Shows like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecWEX.jpg).

I am using a bootstrap 3, with an additional theme of gsdk (Get Sh*t Done Kit). 
If somebody can help me with this, it would be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

### Use Simple [Bootstrap tooltip](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tooltip.asp)

**Positioning Tooltips**

By default, the tooltip will appear on top of the element.

Use the data-placement attribute to set the position of the tooltip on top, bottom, left or the right side of the element:

**Example Below :-**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Tooltip Example</h3>
  <p>The data-placement attribute specifies the tooltip position.</p>
  <ul class="list-inline">
    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hooray!">Top</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Hooray!">Bottom</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Hooray!">Left</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Hooray!">Right</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Another way is simple [Tooltip by css3](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_tooltip)**

```css
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -60px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="text-align:center;">

<h2>Tooltip</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Both didn't work. Could you please check my code above and let me know which area am making it odd?